# How do I set a Boolean config variable to false?

Tags: drush

I can't set a boolean config value to FALSE with drush.

```
pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-set advagg.settings enabled 0 -y

 // Do you want to update enabled key in advagg.settings config?: yes.                                                  

pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-get advagg.settings enabled
'advagg.settings:enabled': false

pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-set advagg.settings enabled true -y

 // Do you want to update enabled key in advagg.settings config?: yes.                                                  

pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-get advagg.settings enabled
'advagg.settings:enabled': true

pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-set advagg.settings enabled false -y

 // Do you want to update enabled key in advagg.settings config?: yes.                                                  

pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-get advagg.settings enabled
'advagg.settings:enabled': true
```

Why does setting it to `false` make it `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the Drush 10 docs for config:set](https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/config_set/). With Drush 10, the `format` option is now `input-format`.

> --input-format[=INPUT-FORMAT]. Format to parse the object. Recognized values: string, yaml [default: string]

For example, to disable core's css aggregation:

```
drush config:set system.performance css.preprocess false --input-format=yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend avoiding such an assumption because the functionality might change with the future versions of Drush.

```
$ drush config-set advagg.settings false --format=yaml -y
```

This is explicit and direct, tested with Drush 8.x.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like `format` no longer works in Drush 10.

Comment: The correct flag is --input-format

Answer (score 0):

When setting a boolean with Drush 8, you need to use `0`, not `false`.

```
pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-get advagg.settings enabled
'advagg.settings:enabled': true

pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-set advagg.settings enabled 0 -y

 // Do you want to update enabled key in advagg.settings config?: yes.                                                  

pk@DC:~/$ lando drush config-get advagg.settings enabled
'advagg.settings:enabled': false
```

**Unfortunately, this does not work in Drush 10.**

Comment: It's salt in the wound that there is no mention of setting a boolean value in the docs https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/config_set/

Evidently setting a boolean is considered an elaborate edge case :/